# Show that $\mu(x\in X: \vert f(x)\vert\geq\alpha\})\leq\frac{1}{\varphi(\alpha)}\int{\varphi\circ\vert f\vert d\mu}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\tau,\mu)$ a measure space and $\varphi:\mathbb{R}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}_{+}$ a function no increasing (i.e., $f(x)\leq f(y)$ is $x\leq y$) and more than zero on $(0,\infty)$. If $f\in$ is such that $\varphi\circ \vert f\vert\in\mathcal{L}^{1}$, then for all $\alpha>0$ $$\mu(x\in X: \vert f(x)\vert\geq\alpha\})\leq\dfrac{1}{\varphi(\alpha)}\int{\varphi\circ\vert f\vert d\mu}$$

Any hint or idea, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a nonnegative, increasing $\varphi$ s.t. $\varphi>0$,

$$
\mu(\{|f|\ge\alpha\})\le\mu(\{\varphi \circ |f| \ge \varphi(\alpha)\})\le\frac{1}{\varphi(\alpha)}\int\varphi \circ |f|d\mu.
$$

The last step is ordinary Markov's inequality.